# value is not fetched using jquery for text box

Tags: jquery, html, input, inputbox

i have a text box and i try to get value like this

```
var comment = $("input#diaMissedPucomments").val();
```

but the value is not fetched at the same time i have used this

```
$('input:checked').each(function() {
          selectedValues =$(this).val()+","+selectedValues ;
        });
```

to get values of selected check boxes it works fine.

```
<div style="display:none;" id="diaMissedPU" title="Missed P/U Comments" >
                       <table>
                            <tr>
                               <td>Enter Comments : </td>
                               <td><input tyep="text" id="diaMissedPucomments" name="diaMissedPucomments" /></td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                    </div>
```

the above is the HTML and i want to get the value of `diaMissedPucomments`

how to do this.

Pleas help me to get this.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers, but still i did not get answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a mistyped `tyep` and must be fixed to `type`

```
<input tyep="text" id="diaMissedPucomments" name="diaMissedPucomments" />
```

must be

```
<input type="text" id="diaMissedPucomments" name="diaMissedPucomments" />
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vnKza/1/

As dakait says enclose your Jquery codes to a Jquery ready handler

```
$(function(){
  var comment = $("input#diaMissedPucomments").val();
  //your other codes
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, but still i did not get answer

Answer (score 3):

You have typo change `tyep="text"` to `type="text"` Id of element is unique you can just use id selector there is no need of using input with id like `input#diaMissedPucomments` if id is unique.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vnKza/)

```
var comment = $("#diaMissedPucomments").val();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to explain why it wasn't working, though. Mahan's finding is more convincing to me.

Answer (score 3):

i see you have spelled  your input type wrong..

```
tyep="text" //here
```

should be

```
<input type="text" id="diaMissedPucomments" name="diaMissedPucomments" />
```

and jquery seems fine..

**UPDATED**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  //make sure you have the javascript codes inside document.ready
    var comment = $("#diaMissedPucomments").val();
 });
```

Comment: If i give default value it works fine but not for dynamic values

Comment: I am sorry, it is not working still, with your updated answer also

Answer (score 2):

like everybody has mentioned that you have a typo, plus make sure you have wrapped the code inside the ready handler

```
$(function(){
 //your code here 
});
```

why it work on jsfiddle then? because with default setting the fiddle wraps the code in document ready